# Debugging Identity Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, visual-studio-2017

I'm rather new to the development of Identity Core 2.0 and Visual Studio 2017. I have a project that uses the new identity core and its running into a problem, however, it is not giving me any errors, so I would like to add the source code to the project so I can further debug and find my problem. However, I have noticed that the structure of nuget packages seems to have dramatically changed, even the packages folder is now gone from the project.

The way I use to do it is I would just remove project references, add the source code and then reference projects as oppose to nuget packages. Now it seems to be more complicated than that. Each package seems to have its own dependency link and I know that there must be an easy way to do this.

To explain better, I have 2 projects, the main project which references a Dapper project, and this Dapper project references the Identity. Now if I look at references of my main project, it shows dapper and under it shows identity along with all of its children projects. Then I look at dapper project references and it shows identity along with all of its children projects.

Now I am sure I am not supposed to go off and update each reference for each child project and parent project, it just seems way too complicated. There must be an easier way, so how can I go about it?

I did find a solution where you add a path to the global.json file, but my projects don't have that file anywhere. Tried creating it, but that didn't work either. I am referring to this solution here: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/debugging-into-asp-net-core-source

Comment: You can step into the framework code with ASP.NET Core 2.0 and VS 2017 15.3: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/debugging-asp-net-core-2-source – It’s not perfect though.

Comment: @poke yeah I tried that, no luck.